# Bearer Token generation and Validation in Owin auth 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I am developing web API 2 services with authentication as bearer Token using oauth 2. I am not able to understand how authorization server create Token and revalidate that Token for subsequent request with that token. I also want to know that if I request token for same user name and password from different machine how server manage the token generation .

Regards

Comment: Plenty of information available on the internet, like http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ or https://blogs.perficient.com/delivery/blog/2017/06/11/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-2-via-owin/

Comment: All information I found only tells that how to consume Owin.auth in your application to generate and Validation of token. But I want to know how Owin.auth service manage the creation and Validation of token internally.

Comment: For that I suggest to take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana).